# Время жизни глобальной переменной vba (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

Периодически сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой. Объявленная глобальная переменная содержащая объект (просто попадаю всегда именно на этом), в какой-то момент работы с книгой и макросами в ней становится `is Nothing`. Борюсь с этой проблемой следующим образом:

```
Public ddict as Dictionary

Function dict() as Dictionary
    if ddict is Nothing Then
        Set ddict = New Dictionary
        # Дальше заполняем заново словарь
    end if
    Set dict = ddict
End Function
```

И в коде использую объект создаваемый функцией `dict`
Сколько я не курил эту тему, везде говорится о том что глобальная переменная живет до момента закрытия книги. Подскажите кто знает, в чем может быть проблема? Почему слетает переменная?

Comment: Или где-то она очищается/переприсваивается, или где-то возникает ошибка объекта... есть и ещё варианты. *Борюсь с этой проблемой следующим образом* Вот что бы не сделать класс - и общаться с ним, а не напрямую с объектом... вылизанными, заведомо бескосячными методами да свойствами.

Comment: PS. ЕМНИП вообще-то говорит, что глобальные переменные нулятся чуть ли не при любой ошибке кода... попробуйте вынести объявление переменной в отдельный модуль, вообще без исполняемого кода.

Comment: @Akina, Не плохой вариант, тоже приходил на ум, и даже скорее всего так и поступлю в оконцовке. Но блин... какого хрена она слетает??? Специально перелопачивал и тестил весь код...  Нет закономерности по слету. Слетает в разных процедурах через рандомное количество времени. PS... И такой вариант попробую. Спасибо

Comment: >> *какого хрена она слетает?* - это надо у Ваших макросов подетальнее поспрашивать :) Не может она сама по себе обнуляться. Глобальная переменная живет до закрытия книги, и это правда. Ее жизнь определяется куском памяти,  который откусываетя при открытии книги. А что в ей содержится - 0 или значение - для жизни неважно.

Comment: @Akina, а что даст вынесения объявления переменной в отдельный модуль? На ее работу и содержание это никак не повлияет.

Comment: @Andrey, поставьте временные (на каккое-то время) проверки с оповещением: если переменная обнулилась, остановка работы кода и указание строки, где это произошло. Конечно, переменная может "уйти" и между двумя проверками, но так можно хотя бы сузить поле поиска. И, конечно же, применять это можно только в случае, если остановка работы не принесет вреда. И, коечно - любой сбой при работе макросов очищает глобальные переменные

Comment: @vikttur *что даст вынесения объявления переменной в отдельный модуль?* Спросите чего попроще... то, что ГП нулятся по ошибке - это точно, а остальное и правда псевдоквазия. Но если не поможет - хуже точно не станет, а структурированность повысится - какой-никакой, а плюсик.